# Merging and comparing two arrays

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, merge

How do I compare each element in two different sets of data, and then merge certain elements of them into a new set of data?

Some info about my methods below. Note:
**Not using java.lang.Collections**

In *one class* I have these calls initializers:

```
    BookCollection collection1 = new BookCollection(100); 
    BookCollection collection2 = new BookCollection(50); 
    BookCollection collection3 = new BookCollection(150);
```

And this call to my method merge(which I am trying to complete)

```
collection3.merge(collection1, collection2);
```

Anndd ***in another class*** my method merge is trying to compare the two sets of data(collection 1 and 2) and if it finds an elements that are equal, only add 1 of those elements to the new collection. Otherwise, add all of the non-equal elements to the new collection.

Here is what I made, but I know that it isn't working. There is a call to one of my other methods findBook that I will post.

```
   public BookCollection merge(BookCollection c1,BookCollection c2){             
   //use this. operator to grab other vars
   BookCollection cNew = new BookCollection(cNew);
      for(String s1: c1)
      if (s1.equals(c2)) {
         cNew = c1;
      }
      cNew = c1 + s1; 
}
```

Annddd

```
   private int findBook(String isbn){
   // iterate all the Book elements in the collection array
      for(int i = 0; i <= collection.length; i++){
   // check if the current book isbn matches the one provided argument
         if (collection[i].getIsbn().equals(isbn))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be far shorter than that.

I'll give you some tips because the idea is not give plain solutions and this question I'm pretty sure is homework.

**If the question is homework add 'homework' tag**

**Tips:**

- Your main method doesn't have any loop. How are gonna iterate over the collections?
- Books as objects they are should have an `equals` method. If that method is correctly implemented (you should define what is a method begin equals to another), then you just can compare b1.equals(b2)
- Collections have `contains` method to check if it contains (by using equals) other book
- `Math.min` method calculates the minimum between two integers or doubles (there are two versions)
- Also, to be complete, if your collections are of a certain type your books should implement hashCode in a compatible way with equals (but my guess is you don't know what hashing is yet, and you'll not use that kind of collections)

So first of all: devise an algorithm. The simpler the better. In plain English.
Just then try to implement that. You'll see the code is much simpler and tidy if you try to program a previous well thought concept.

**Edit:**

Ensure to know what a `Collection` is in Java world (tip: is a general interface implemented by several distinct more specific classes).

And don't use the word array unless you are using real arrays (and given your exercise proposal it doesn't seem you need it).

Comment: I convert the c1 and c2 collections to strings and then I pass them to findBook method which iterates over them and returns an integer, which is then assigned to the values of index1/2. I wrote a for iteration, but am getting this error: error: _int cannot be dereferenced_ could you check my edit?

Comment: Nope. Didn't get into the detail of the code but seems overcomplicated. Believe me. You don't need crazy transformations from book to string, to find an int, etc. And, if you want to produce a list with books in BOTH input collections you should iterate over one of the lists and try to find if that items are in the other collection or not.
More important. You are passing Book to you merge method. Which class of collection is that? That's ONE item inside the collection. You should be passing Collection<Book>, List<Book> or Set<Book> or something.
That's why I'm telling you think all over again.

Comment: What I've meant is: maybe you have trouble mapping between what you want to do and the code needed to do so. But the first problem is finding how to represent you problem and what do you want to do with your objects (in an abstract way). What we call algorithm. You don't even decided how to represent a collection (your code doesn't even mention any Collection, List or Set). And WTF is that double you're returning? Shouldn't you be returning another collection?

Comment: I greatly simplified my question, so have a look.

Comment: Yeap. You've read my comment about not finding the word collection in it and you added it. Either you professor wants you to use arrays (because collections are too complex yet, I'm afraid) or you should use collections. However certain things in the code demonstrate you are not understanding (pre-allocate 150 spaces even if you're not using arrays, but later you want to create collection again in method, you don't have a loop).

Comment: I will keep going at it. Could I possible get an up vote for my reconstruction of the question?

Comment: You don't have to program anything. You're not yet able to. You need to EXPRESS IN PLAIN ENGLISH what you procedure for building the new collection (or array or whatever) will be. You need to have that right FIRST if you want to write some line of code. But it's evident you are lost and if we tell you how to do it it would be either unhelpful or would be a different solution that the requested one (don't know you you are supposed to use java.lang.Collections). So, do yourself a favor and 1) try to understand what your code is doing 2) acknowledge it's not doing what you want and...

Comment: 3) ask a fellow student if you're lost. She/he will know better what's intended and will tell you the first steps.
Here in SO you'll get concrete solutions to concrete problems. Not a solution for an exercise. Less if you show that you are not understanding the basics.

Comment: The downvote is not because you're question is clear or not. Is because you're not asking something concrete.